# Combining disabled and enabled dates - not working

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I am using the **flatpickr** calendar. It supports various functions for enabling/disabling dates, but I can't seem to get both enabling and disabling to work simultaneously.

I am trying to disable Sundays and and also disable all dates in the future (counted from a date I generate using PHP).

Disabling Sundays did work before I added the second function to only enable dates in the past, incl. today.

Here is the code:

```
"enable": [
    function(date) {
        // return true to enable
        return (date.getDate() <= <?php echo $nextDateAllowed; ?>);
    }
],
"disable": [
    function(date) {
    // return true to disable
        return (date.getDay() === 0);
    }
],
locale: {
    firstDayOfWeek: 1
}
```

Thinking this could be because of the order of the functions, I swapped them (`disable` was first, `enable` was second), but when I open the calendar, the previous Sunday is still active.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use only enable like this

```
"enable": [
    function(date) {
        // return true to enable
        return (date.getDate() <= <?php echo $nextDateAllowed; ?> && date.getDay() !== 0 );
    }
]
```

work fine for me :D

Comment: Thank you! This does the trick. Honestly, I had long abandoned this project and forgotten about this problem.